# django logout() doesn't show template

Tags: python, django, logout

Im using the Django function for loggin out and it doesnt show my template. the codes here:

**Views.py**

```
class Logout(View):
    #import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
    template_name = ['cost_control_app/logout.html']

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return render(request, self.template_name)

    def logout_view(request):
        logout(request)
        print ("ya")
        return render(request, self.template_name)
```

**Urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = patterns(
    '',
    url(r'^logout/$', views.Logout.as_view(), name = "logout"),
)
```

And the template:

**logout.html**

```
{% extends 'base_cost_control.html' %}
{% block contentsubbase %}

<head>
<body>
    <div>
        <h2> Logged out succefully </h2>
        <br>
        <a href="{% url 'cost_control_app:login' %}">Iniciar sesión</a>
    </div>
</body>
</head>

{% endblock contentsubbase %}
```

in my main page im using an a href layer to point a that url :

```
<a href="{% url 'cost_control_app:logout' %}">Logout</a>
```

but itś not working, it only redirects me to a complete empty page called logout and if i go back in my browser im still logged in.

Comment: `template_name` should not be a list, you also don't need the `def logout_view(request):` block in there

Comment: mmm doesn't work neither =(

Comment: In your template I see you are enclosing the `body` block in `<head>..</head>`. `body` has to be outside of `head`. In your `base_cost_control.html` do you define a block called `contentsubbase` ?  And finally, there's no logic that does actually log a user out, it's just a template at this stage

Comment: and also have a look at the docs at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/default/#all-authentication-views, there are built-in views you can use and a complete example

Comment: Thanks to all for your answers, but that's not the problem....doing a trace i found that the function 

def logout_view(request):

It's returning none....what am i doing wrong ??

Answer (score 1):

1. define your template_name as string

   template_name = "cost_control_app/logout.html"
2. Your template should be place in your project `app_folder/templates/app_name`
3. You can also define template_dirs in settings.py as follows

   TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
       os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
   )

now create a folder in your project named `templates` and put your templates on each app in a folder correspond to `app_name`

Step 3 is not necessary and is just an alternate

Comment: Thanks for your answers, but that's not the problem, i already did that and all other templates work just fine....doing a trace i found that the function 

def logout_view(request):

It's returning none....what am i doing wrong ??

Answer (score 0):

Django 3.1: If you don't need to control the logout process, you can let Django's standard authentication system take care of it. No need to write a view or modify urlpatterns, simply direct the user to a template you specify in the GET request:

```
<a href="{% url 'logout' %}?next=myapp/mytemplates/logout.html">Logout now</a>
```

This assumes you have the default settings ('django.contrib.auth' in installed apps, 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware' in middleware, and 'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth' in template context processors) in settings.py.